# How many integer nonnegative solutions are there to the pair of equations: $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3...+ x_6 = 20 $ and $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 7$.

Tags: combinatorics

This is for my combinatorics class so I took the  approach that we've been taught in class, though we haven't been showed how to do it for a pair of equations. So the second question can be solved by $${7 + 2\choose 2}$$, given that I can substitute back into my first question so $$(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ) + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 20 $$ Treating the second equation as one we can solve the first equation through $${13 + 2\choose 2} $$ Since both equations are indep. of each other, we need to multiply them. Is this right or have I completely butchered it? Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: This is exactly right; you’ve understood perfectly.

Comment: Alternatively you can put $x_i= 1 + y_i$ so that the new variables can be zero too, the numbers in the constraints become smaller and then use stars and bars